# Need user to be able to download 2 files consecutively in a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to handle the need to a user to download 2 files. I'm using *send_data* to send the file to the browser. How can I allow the user to get two dynamically generated files from one request, **OR** what is a better alternative to do this. A simple example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
  def data_out
    output = "foo foo foo "
    send_data(output,:type => "text/csv",:filename => "foo.txt")

    output2 = "bar bar bar"
    send_data(output2,:type => "text/csv",:filename => "bar.txt" )
  end
```

When calling data_out, only *bar.txt* file is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would zip them first using RubyZip, then present the zip file as a single download. Smaller download size, faster download.

Answer (score 2):

Call each one from a hidden iframe.

You can add an iframe to the DOM with this file as its `src`.